# ReactJS - moving list items between components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create two components, one that holds the results of an API call from iTunes. I want to be able to click on any one of the items and move it to the empty component, `moveResults`, and then move it back to `searchResults` if it is clicked again. From other exercises, I feel like I am close, however I keep getting an error about the `this.handleEvent = this.handleEvent.bind(this)`. Any ideas as to where I might have gone wrong and some possible solutions?

```
 var App = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        searchResults: [],
        moveResults: []
    }

},

this.handleEvent = this.handleEvent.bind(this);

showResults: function(response) {
    this.setState({
        searchResults: response.results,
        moveResults: []
    })
},

search: function(URL) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: URL,
        success: function(response) {
            this.showResults(response);
        }.bind(this)
    });
},

handleEvent(trackId) {
    const isInSearchResults = this.state.searchResults.includes(trackId);

    this.setState({
        searchResults: isInSearchResults ? this.state.searchResults.filter(i => i !== trackId) : [...this.state.searchResults, trackId],
        moveResults: isInSearchResults ? [...this.state.moveResults, trackId] : this.state.moveResults.filter(i => i !== trackId)
    });
},

componentDidMount() {
    this.search('https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=broods')
},

render: function(){
    return (
        <div>
            <Results searchResults={this.state.searchResults} handleEvent={this.handleEvent}/>
            <Results searchResults={this.state.moveResults} handleEvent={this.handleEvent} />
        </div>
    );
  }
});


var Results = React.createClass({
   render: function(){
    let handleEvent = this.props.handleEvent;
    var resultItems = this.props.searchResults.map(function(result) {
        return <ResultItem key={result.trackId} trackName={result.trackName} onClick={() => handleEvent(resultItems.id)} />
    });
    return(
        <ul>
            {resultItems}
        </ul>
    );
  }
});
var ResultItem = React.createClass({
   render: function(){
    return <li> {this.props.trackName} </li>;
   }
 });

  ReactDOM.render(
       <App />, document.getElementById('root')
   );
```

Comment: I think you're mixing syntax necessary with `class MyComponent extends React.Component` and `React.createClass()` . Try removing the handle event binding line entirely.

Comment: @gvfordo Thanks! That got rid of the error, however I am not getting any sort of response or action when I am clicking on one of the list items

Comment: your searchResult objects aren't just an array if trackIds,  so your includes() and filter() calls won't work as you're expecting them to.  If a result looks like { id: 123, name: 'track name' },  to filter it based on id you would results.filter(result => result.id !=== trackId) etc.

Comment: @gvfordo Hey, sorry to be a bother. I just cannot figure out what I am doing wrong and I've been at it all day..I was wondering if you could give my code a look over? I would really appreciate it: https://jsfiddle.net/justinmckenzie/499ymo8s/

Comment: Here's a working fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/6k9ncbr6/  The main problem you had is that you have to pass the click handler all the way through to some actual Dom element.  Your original code had an onClick prop on the ResultItem,  but the ResultItem definition never used it as the onClick for the actual li that was rendered.

Comment: @gvfordo Thank you, I really appreciate the time and help!

Comment: @gvfordo hi, I'm going over this exercise (in your jsfiddle) again to make sure I can really get this down. I understand everything, however the only thing that throws me off is when you're setting the state is showResults, what is the significance of the 'results' in `response.results`? I cannot seem to trace it anywhere else, and I notice when I remove it that it no longer works. Can you give some insight on what exactly `.results` means?

Comment: If you log the response,  `console.log(response)` . you'll see it has two attributes.  { resultCount: 50, results: Array(50) }.  So the response.results is the actual array of objects that you want as the data for the component.  That was copied from your original code and left unchanged.  A better name for the function might be "handleResponse".  Although the actual work is so brief here you could also just call setState directly in the success handler.

Comment: @gvfordo thank you!